# "Pageless" Flex: Refreshing Ads Problem

Tags: apache-flex

I've got a Flex 3 website. I set-up adBrite in an iFrame to serve ads, and it works fine. I've got 2 ad zones in 2 iFrames.

My problem is that as Flex has a "pageless" architecture, I only get credit for one hit even if the user clicks every button on the site. In short, I get one pageview instead of several.

adBrite said that if I can figure out a way to refresh the ads when the user selects a new item in my navigation menu, they're cool with it. They suggested just refreshing the whole app. I wonder if there is a better and easier way to tackle this problem. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've got it.

On my comboBox I added a call to changeAd() on the valueCommit event.

In this function, I had:

myIframe.callIFrameFunction('reloadMe');

In the HTML page, I added a reloadMe function that reloaded the iFrame.